# Call admin ajax using absolute url? Relative URL breaks (frontend ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, urls

Hoping There is an easy way to do this/I am doing something horridly wrong:
I'm trying to simply display a list of post titles. When a user clicks on the title it will display that said title's content into a previously empty div on the same page with ajax.

however it won't work correctly if I switch around the permalinks etc or have a post that's url is a few directories deeps (ie: site.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/page, or site.com/dir1/page). It will ONLY work if I have site.com?p=23

BECAUSE of this relative url in my ajax request:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

//whenever a title is clicked on: run this request
$('.get_post').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $portfolioPostId = $(this).data('postid');  

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  //WON'T LOAD on any url that ISN'T like this format: site.com/?p=123
        data: {
            action: 'my_post',
            postid: $portfolioPostId
        },
        success: function(data){

            $('#well').html(' ');
            $('#well').html(data);




        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

            console.log(errorThrown) + '\n';

        }

    });


});


});
```

So INSTEAD of having `url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'`, how could I instead use an ABSOLUTE URL? Or is there something better that could be done?

**EDIT:** 
**SOLUTION TO MY ISSUE:**

Thanks to Rarst's answer I was able to find a way to pass the absolute URL.

On my php file where I enqueue my script, I also sent through an object called `psAjax_object` that contained the absolute URL to `admin-ajax.php`

```
function frontend_js(){

    wp_enqueue_script('shuffle_ajax', plugins_url( NAME . '/public/js/portfolio_grid_ajax.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );

    //creates the property for the 'psAjax_object'
    $localizedArray = array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));

    //allows my portfolio_grid_ajax.js file to access 'psAjax_object'
    wp_localize_script('shuffle_ajax', 'psAjax_object', $localizedArray);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'frontend_js');
```

and then in my js file i can access the absolute url by typing `psAjax_object.ajax_url`

Comment: You'll need to localize your script.. after you enqueue it to the frontend.  Pass the `admin_ajax()` url in a javascript variable.. then access it in your ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal practice is to generate URL on PHP side ( [`admin_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/admin_url/) ) and provide it to your script via localization functionality ( [`wp_localize_script()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_localize_script/) ). It is documented in Codex under [Ajax on the Viewer-Facing Side](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).